# Function to match string to one of many regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have the following function, which works:

```
String.prototype.matchAny = function(patterns) {
    var that = this;
    var matched = false;

    // Iterate patterns and return key of first match
    $.each(patterns, function(i, v) {
        if (that.match(v)) {
            matched = i;
            return false;
        }
    });

    return matched;
};
```

It will return the index in `patterns` of the first matched regular expression for the string. For example:

```
"blah".matchAny([/a/, /z/]);       // 0
"blah".matchAny({z: /z/, a: /a/]); // "a"
```

However, this solution feels clunky to me. I've had some success using [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), and while it's a lot more elegant, I can't find a way to get the result I want (return the key from `patterns` that matched).

Is there something I'm missing? More specifically, **is there a built-in function (JavaScript/jQuery) that can produce the same results?**

Comment: if you want the result, you probably want Array.map + Array.filter, where you pass in a function to `map` that either returns "false" or the matched thing, and then pass a function to `filter` that's simply `function(v) { return !!v; }` in ES5, or `v => !!v` in ES6 notation. Also, I'd recommend against tacking it onto the String prototype. It's just syntax, "string.matchAny(regs) is just as much typing as matchAny(string,regs), but the latter is much safer than the former. Alternatively, using a `for .. of)` (ES6 only) would let you exit early

Comment: Thanks, Mike! I'll play with this and see if I can come up with something.